# Downcase a list for specific cases but not others

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a list of strings (which consist of Letters, upper and lower case, Numbers, and Special Characters) that have incorrect Case formatting. The goal I am trying to achieve is to down-case all instances of list elements that are of the following formatting:

```
['ALLUPPERCASE', 'ALL_UPPER_WITH_UNDERSCORES', 'ALL-UPPER-EXCEPT (text here)']
```

In layman's terms any element that is either, all upper case, all uppercase with either underscores '_' or hyphens '-' (Can have both underscores and hyphens in same element, or all uppercase except at the end there is a space and then a phrase that is lower case but in parenthesis.

I would like for all other cases of elements in the list to stay in their case formatting... If a element is formatted like this, `The_Text_Here`, then that element would stay in its formatting.

The first solution I thought would work would be to just look at the case of the element before the '(' and then just to disregard anything after the '('. I do not believe that the Hyphens or Underscores will affect whether or not the text is read as all uppercase; however, I was unable to find for sure if they do.

Imagine the following code as a format to follow:

```
L1 = ['THRESHOLD_BAND', 'THRESHOLD_BAND (copy)', 'TICKER', 'TICKER-TWO',
      'Title C (copy)', 'Title C (copy) (copy)']

for i in L1:
    **add code**
    output = **add code**

print('\n'.join(output))

**terminal**
$threshold_band
 threshold_band (copy)
 ticker
 ticker-two
 Title C (copy)
 Title C (copy) (copy)
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples so that we can better understand this question?

Comment: @snnguyen The examples are in the code snippet.

Comment: What should happen with a single uppercase character?

Comment: If there is a single uppercase character then that character should be downcased. @Barmar

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a similar approach you mentioned in your question, but check for any lowercase appearing in the string instead of matching for uppercase **(with no imports)**:

```
[x if any(y.islower() for y in x.split('(')[0]) else x.lower() for x in L1]
```

which outputs:

```
['threshold_band', 
 'threshold_band (copy)', 
 'ticker', 
 'ticker-two',
 'Title C (copy)', 
 'Title C (copy) (copy)']
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well without importing re, will test this, however I already have re in the script so dealing with importing isn't too big of an issue. @Austin

Comment: Upon testing this case, it appears to function great for what I needed to accomplish. Also does not require the importing of regex. Thanks for this! @Austin

Comment: @ChandlerCree If the answer helped you accept the answer and upvote. Thanks are unnecessary. Comments should be used for *clarifications* or *suggestions*.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression that matches the patterns you want to downcase.

```
import re
def maybe_downcase(s):
    if re.match(r'^[A-Z_-]+(?:\s\(.*\))?$', s):
        return s.lower()
    else:
        return s

output = [maybe_downcase(x) for x in L1]
```

The regexp matches a sequence of uppercase letters, underscores, and hyphens, optionally followed by a space and anything in parentheses.

Comment: Hello, this works just as desired, thanks for the quick response. I realized I failed to mention a possible case scenario. What would I add to the expression if I wanted to also down-case an instance like following: `'THRESHOLD_BAND123' -> 'threshold_band123'` @Barmar

Comment: @ChandlerCree, The easiest way you can do is check for lowercase which works for the additional scenario you mentioned as well. Please see my answer.

Comment: You can add `\d` to the character class with A-Z. @ChandlerCree

Answer (score 2):

Does this give you the right output?

```
L1 = ['THRESHOLD_BAND', 'THRESHOLD_BAND (copy)', 'TICKER', 'TICKER-TWO',
      'Title C (copy)', 'Title C (copy) (copy)']

L2 = []
for strng in L1:
    s0, *s1 = strng.split('(', 1)
    s0 = s0.lower() if s0 == s0.upper() else s0
    L2.append('('.join((s0, *s1)))

print(*L2, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
threshold_band
threshold_band (copy)
ticker
ticker-two
Title C (copy)
Title C (copy) (copy)
```

Comment: This gives the correct output as well, thanks will experiment with all instances for efficiency. @Heike